# CLT of the left singular vectors of i.i.d. data matrix

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, asymptotics, random-matrices, eigenvector

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be $(n \times p)$-dimensional random matrix ($n > p$) whose rows $\mathbf{x}_i$ are i.i.d. with some finite moments:
$$
   \mathbf{X}^\top = [\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots \mathbf{x}_n]^\top.
$$
By the singular decomposition, we can obtain
$$
   \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{V}^\top = \mathbf{U}_{:r} \mathbf{D}_{:r} \mathbf{V}_{:r}^\top,
$$
where $r$ is the rank of $\mathbf{X}$ which may $r<p$. Notice that here I used a Matlab colon notation ":" to denote submatrices
\begin{align*}
   \mathbf{U}_{:r} &:= [\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_r],  \\
\mathbf{D}_{:r} &:= \operatorname{diag}([d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_r]), \\
\mathbf{V}_{:r} &:= [\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_r],
\end{align*}
(Notice that $\mathbf{U}_{:r}$ is not a square matrix, so $\mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \mathbf{U}_{:r} = \mathbf{I}$, but $\mathbf{U}_{:r}\mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \neq \mathbf{I}$). Then from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/440378/159685), we can know that there is some $C$ such that
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{U}_{:r} \mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \mathbf{y} \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} C
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$, where the elements of $\mathbf{y}$ are i.i.d.\ and independent to $\mathbf{X}$.
Then my question is

> **Question.**
>
> Can we say
> \begin{align*}
>   \sqrt{n} \bigg( \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{U}_{:r} \mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \mathbf{y} - C \bigg) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}} \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2),
> \end{align*}
> for some $\mu$ and $\sigma$? (Here $\xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}}$ is convergence in law.)

From the [previous question's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/441368/159685), I can easily apply classical CLT for the term $\frac{1}{n} \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{X} \mathbf{V}_0 \mathbf{D}_0^{-2} \mathbf{O}^\top \mathbf{V}_0^\top \mathbf{X}^\top \mathbf{y}$, but I'm not sure how to handle $O_{\mathbb{P}}(1/\sqrt{n})$ term in that answer.

It would be really appreciated if you give any help.

Thanks,

Comment: You said $\mathbf X$ is an $n\times p$ "data matrix". It seems unclear whether you meant that $\mathbf X$ is some sort of matrix-valued random variable or is to be taken as a constant. If the former, then in order to think about
$$\frac{1}{n} \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{U}_{:r} \mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \mathbf{y} \xrightarrow {\mathbb{P}} C,
$$
one would have to think about the probability distribution of the $n\times r$ random matrix $\mathbf U.$ If the latter,$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ then you could skip everything about the columns of $\mathbf U$ being the left singular vectors of some $n\times p$ matrix $\mathbf X$ and just say $\mathbf U$ is an $n\times r$ constant (non-random) matrix with orthonormal columns and $\mathbf y$ is an $n\times1$ random column vector. $\qquad$

Comment: Since the columns of $\mathbf U_{:r}$ are orthonormal, the random vector $\mathbf{U}_{:r} \mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \mathbf{y}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf y$ onto the column space of $\mathbf U_{:r},$ and the matrix $\mathbf U_{:r} \mathbf U_{:r}^\top$ is an idempotent matrix, so that $\mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{U}_{:r} \mathbf{U}_{:r}^\top \mathbf{y}$ is the square of the norm of that orthogonal projection. $\qquad$

Comment: 1. $\mathbf{X}$ is a random matrix. 2. That's the key problem of my former question. 3. I know that it is the orthogonal projection, and I know where to converge. What I want here is that can we establish central limit theorem by debiasing the limit. Sorry for making confusion.